# How to make a datetime column the index in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am working on a code where data is called from a CSV file; it turns the dates in a column called indexDatetime to datetime. It is supposed to set that column to be the index. But when I use .set_index('indexDatetime'), the index does not change.

Comment: You need to tell it to modify data frame in place. `.set_index('indexDatetime', inplace=True)`

Comment: @Psidom thank you so much

Comment: Alternatively, assign the updated dataframe to the original, as in `df = df.set_index('indexDatetime')`